# MathJax font overwrite sphinx bootstrap font

Tags: html, python-sphinx, mathjax

Why does MathJax re-render the math fonts on HTML website?

This is my webpage look like at one second:

[image]

Nice and happy, and then one second later...

[image]

and the whole format now looks really weird. Is there a way to stop MathJax rendering the font? I am using sphinx documentation with bootstrap theme.

EDIT: Live example [here](http://qth20.user.srcf.net/documentation/tutorial/nonlinear.html).

Comment: You might want to [read the docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/font-support.html)? Though the bad baseline alignment looks like a bug; a live sample would be good.

Comment: This is due to the [fast-preview extension](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/fast-preview.html) that tries to display your math quickly (but with some loss of quality in some situations), and then re-renders it more slowly with higher quality (in general).  You can disable it if you don't want that feature.

Comment: I have just added a live example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by CSS syntax

```
.math{ overflow: auto}
```

Into

```
.math{ overflow: inherit} // or hidden
```